# this is a data compress java code, Nothing comes out of this program any idea why?

Tags: java, compression

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package FileComp;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;


public class Compress {


    public static void compress(File source, File destination) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(source);
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        GZIPOutputStream gz = new GZIPOutputStream(fo);
        int read;

        while((read = fs.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            gz.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        gz.finish();
        gz.close();
        fo.close();
        fs.close();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File source = new File("C:\\Users\\MASTER\\Desktop\\z.txt");
        File destination = new File("C:\\Users\\MASTER\\Desktop\\oCompress.txt");
        try
        {
            compress(source, destination);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Functionally you are missing call to [`flush()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush()) on your `OutputStream`. Technically the code has lots of space for improvement.

Comment: @JigarJoshi - That's not necessary.  The `close()` will flush

Comment: @Stephe You are right. Thanks for correction.

Comment: I could not see any *functional* problems, so I copied the code, tweaked the filenames, compiled and ran it.  For me, it just worked.  It generated a compressed file.  Your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: One thing that is strange is that you named the output file `oCompress.txt`. When you zip something the result is not a plain text file, so you shouldn't name it with the `.txt` extension.

Comment: @Jesper even with removing the extension, still no output

Comment: Are you seeing error messages that you are not telling us about?  How are you compiling / running the code?

Comment: @StephenC no error messages, everything works fine but no output

Comment: Is the output file created?

Comment: How are you compiling / running the code?